# Why I cannot stop post-back even by returning false in an asp.net LinkButton here?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, postback, linkbutton

I have one LinkButton that I want to stop post-back on confirmation.

But the problem is even I click CANCEL on confirmation, it still post-backs.

How I bind it to confirmation func is like this:

```
LinkButton lbtn = e.Row.FindControl("btnDelete") as LinkButton;
            lbtn.CommandArgument = e.Row.RowIndex.ToString();

            const string js = @"confirmDelete(this,{0})";
            lbtn.Attributes["onClick"] = string.Format(js, e.Row.RowIndex);
```

And this is the function:

```
function confirmDelete(lbtn, rowIndex) {
        var tr = $(lbtn).closest('tr');
        var formalColor= tr.css('background');
        tr.css('background', '#FF0000');

        var retVal = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?");
        tr.css('background', formalColor);

        alert(retVal);
        return retVal;
    };
```

So what should I do to prevent post-back if the user clicks CANCEL -is it a special case for Linkbuttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use

```
return confirmDelete(this,{0})
```

Comment: Just noticed after posting the question :) But I will accept your answer as it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
return confirmDelete(this,{0})
```

...will cancel the event if the function returns false.